# How to set different intents for notifications fired from firebase functions

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, google-cloud-functions

I need an explanation about something very important. Is it possible to set different methods to notifications fired by `Firebase` functions so that they both open different activities when they are clicked? I tried something like this:

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("name"));
        } else if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            showNotification1(remoteMessage.getData().get("name"));
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

        }
    }

    private void showNotification1(String name) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Important")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText(name)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }


    private void showNotification(String name) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Lecture Notes")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText(name)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

But upon doing so, the first method is always called. Am I doing something wrong?
How do I better format the coding in my Javascript file to distinguish the type of notification coming in? Below is my Javascript file.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Lecture_Materials/{MIS}/Systems_Devt/{Systems_DevtId}/name')
    .onWrite(( change,context) =>{

    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();
    var str1 = "Lecture material uploaded(Systems Dev't): " + eventSnapshot;
    console.log(eventSnapshot);

    var topic = "Management.Information.System";
    var payload = {
        data: {
            name: str1,
        }
    };

    // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
            // contents of response.
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            return;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
    });

    exports.sendNotification1 = functions.database.ref('/Lecture_Materials/{MIS}/Enterprise_Sys/{Enterprise_SysId}/name')
    .onWrite(( change,context) =>{

    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();
    var str = "Lecture material uploaded(Enterprise Systems): " + eventSnapshot;
    console.log(eventSnapshot);

    var topic = "Management.Information.System";
    var payload = {
        data: {
            name: str,
        }
    };

    // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
            // contents of response.
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            return;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Seems like you get to choose what activity you want to launch when you build your PendingIntent.  You'll probably benefit by looking over the API docs for it.

Comment: Doug, it's just not about the activity I want to be launched when the notification is clicked. How do I specify the kind of notification that must be shown when the function is fired? Because I would like to use the messaging feature of the notification API since I have a chatting feature in my android application.

Comment: Maybe put more stuff in the data payload to tell your client code what to show?

Comment: I know about adding more stuff to the data payload. Isn't there anyway to format the notification coming in from Android Studio? Really confused here.